# Face an error on enable the job

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure, jobs, plsqldeveloper

```
EXEC dbms_scheduler.enable('temp_job');
```

Does not execute, displays the error

> ORA-000900:invalid SQL statement

```
BEGIN 
    dbms_scheduler.create_job (job_name => 'temp_job', 
    job_type => 'stored_procedure', job_action => 'p_TIJ', 
    start_date => '23-july-2018 05.00.00 pm', 
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1', 
    end_date => '23-july-2018 5.59.00 pm', auto_drop => FALSE, 
    comments => 'my_job') ; 
END;
```

Comment: my job code > Begin dbms_scheduler.create_job ( job_name => 'temp_job', job_type => 'stored_procedure', job_action => 'p_TIJ', start_date => '23-july-2018 05.00.00 pm', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1', end_date => '23-july-2018 5.59.00 pm', auto_drop => false, comments => 'my_job' ); END;

Comment: Please **edit your question** when adding information or other improvements. Code is especially hard to read in a comment because of the poor formatting.

Comment: `EXEC` is a SQL* Plus command. I'm not familiar with Plsqldeveloper, but i think you should chose an editor option where it will execute as a script, rather than as sql.